# Importing Auth0 Lock into a React component in Meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6, auth0

I'm setting up a new Meteor 1.3 project and am having trouble integrating [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). I'm following the tutorial [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/meteor), but to make things more complicated I'm using ES2015 modules as well as React, so I'm translating as I go.

After running `meteor add auth0:lock` the tutorial says I should make the following JS run on the client:

```
Template.Auth0Login.events({
  'click button.login'(event, instance) {
    lock.show();
  },
}
```

So my `app/imports/ui/components/Navbar.jsx` file looks like this:

```
1| import React, {Component} from 'react';
2| 
3| export default class Navbar extends Component {
4|   render() {
5|     return (
6|       <button class='signin' onClick={lock.show()}>Sign In</button>
7|      )
8|   }
9| }
```

The rendered page is blank, with the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

If I remove `onClick={lock.show()}`, the button displays. And that makes sense – how could it know what "lock" is without importing it? So I found an import line on the Auth0 [React tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login) and dropped it in:

```
1| import React, {Component} from 'react';
2| import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';
3| 
4| export default class Navbar extends Component {
5|   ...
```

Causing the following console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'auth0-lock'
```

I tried renaming the imported module to `auth0:lock` en lieu of the meteor package, to no avail.

Does anyone know how to import Lock into a given React component so that these functions can be used? Or is there another way?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock ?

```
    // Initialize Auth0Lock with your `clientID` and `domain`
    var lock = new Auth0Lock('xxxxxx', '<account>.auth0.com');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I'm excited about this direction, however as I am using ES2015 imports, I get a new error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Auth0Lock is not defined` so I suspect I need to figure out a proper import line for the React component file. I tried `import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';`, `import Auth0Lock from 'auth0:lock'`, and `import Auth0Lock from 'Auth0Lock';`, none of which were successful. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Teagan. `import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';` works fine for me with ES2015 imports. What package manager do you use with meteor? Are you sure Auth0Lock is in the declared dependencies of your project? Since you use React you can also have a look at [auth0-react-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-react-lock)

Comment: Since I am not familiar with Meteor and Atmosphere, I am not sure my input is of any use to you. You have a 'packages' file in your project like [this one](https://github.com/auth0/meteor-auth0/blob/master/examples/auth0-meteor-sample/.meteor/packages) right?

Comment: vwrobel that it works for you makes me very hopeful! I added Auth0 with `meteor add auth0:lock` so I see `auth0:lock` in my `.meteor/packages` file. Maybe I should try using npm instead and adding it to my root `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes you could try npm. I used `npm install auth0-lock --save` for my project.

Comment: auth0 is possible the worst service I've ever used